# SQL Server Express - invalid cursor state after backup

Tags: c++, sql-server, backup, sql-server-2012-express

I'm encountering a "strange" problem and I have no idea of what is happening (I'm new to SQL Server).

I'm doing a database backup to a backup device which I created in SQL Server Management Studio. I'm running a simple query

```
BACKUP DATABASE abc TO abcBackupDevice
```

and this works fine, but any following SQLExecDirect returns "Invalid cursor state" error.

I'm running a C++ app in Visual Studio 2012 and SQL Server 2012 Express as well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It was all to do with unhandled result sets. If your query returns some data that data needs to handled or discarded with a SQLMoreResults.